# How to use only one time bfs to solve this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

The problem is uva1599, Visit https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=4474

The problem is roughly described as below:

The labyrinth consists of n rooms connected by m path. Each path is colored into some color ci. Find the ideal path from the room number 1 to the
room number n. The path is the ideal path if its color sequence is the lexicographically smallest among shortest paths.（2<=n<=100000, 1<=m<=200000, 1<=c<=10^9）

I could use bfs from the end room to get the shortest path for each room, and use bfs again to search from the beginning if there is multi paths with the same length of path and different colors.

How to solve this problem with only one bfs?

I try to start from the end room using bfs get the shortest path and color sequence for each room. The idael path is stored in the room 1's color sequence.

Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: What you've tried?

Comment: My code is in the first answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. The error is runtime error

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class IdealPath {
    //store the path between two rooms, if there is a path between room i and j, then graph[i][j] = 1
    public static int [][]graph;
    //store the color between two rooms
    public static int [][]color;
    //store the shortest path to the end room for each room
    public static int []distance;
    //store the ideal color sequence for each room
    public static String []color_seq;
    //use for bfs
    public static Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

    /**
     * Initialize parameters
     * @param n
     */
    public static void init(int n){
        graph = new int[n][n];
        color = new int[n][n];
        distance = new int[n];
        color_seq = new String[n];
        queue.clear();
    }

    /**
     * use bfs to find the ideal path
     * @param n
     */
    public static void bfs(int n){
        //init the end room
        distance[n-1] = 0;
        color_seq[n-1] = "";
        queue.add(n-1);
        //loop until the queue is empty
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int node = queue.poll();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                //there is a path
                if (graph[node][i] == 1){
                    //the room is not visited or is visited by the last floor
                    if (distance[i] == 0 || distance[i] == distance[node] + 1) {
                        distance[i] = distance[node] + 1;  //add the distance
                        String str = color[i][node] + " " + color_seq[node];  //generate the color sequence
                        if (color_seq[i] == null)
                            color_seq[i] = str.trim();
                        //choose the ideal color sequence for the room
                        else
                            color_seq[i] = compare(color_seq[i], str) ? str.trim() : color_seq[i].trim();
                        queue.add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * return true if str2 < str1
     * @param str1
     * @param str2
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean compare(String str1, String str2){
        String []arr2 = str2.trim().split(" ");
        String []arr1 = str1.trim().split(" ");
        //assume the lengths of arr1 and arr2 are same
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr2[i].compareTo(arr1[i]) < 0)
                return true;
        }
        return  false;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            //input
            int n = input.nextInt();
            int m = input.nextInt();
            init(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int node1 = input.nextInt() - 1;
                int node2 = input.nextInt() - 1;
                //ignore the path to itself
                if (node1 != node2) {
                    graph[node1][node2] = graph[node2][node1] = 1;
                    int c = input.nextInt();
                    //choose the smallest path if it has multi path
                    color[node1][node2] = color[node2][node1] = (color[node1][node2] == 0) ? c : Math.min(c, color[node1][node2]);
                }
            }
            //use bfs to find the ideal path
            bfs(n);
            //output
            //the ideal path is stored in the color_seq[0]
            String res = color_seq[0].trim();
            System.out.println((res.length() + 1) / 2);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
```